# 100% height of parent. All parent heights are dynamic

Tags: css, html, height, stretch

I've read through tons of questions and articles and I can't seem to figure this out.

Here's a rough example of my layout structure:

```
body  
- div 1 (header)  
- div 2 (main content wrapper)  
- - div 2a  
- - - div 2a1  
- - - div 2a2  
- - - - div 2a2a (this div needs to fit 100% height of it's parent - div 2a2)  
- - - div 2a3  
- - div 2b  
- div 3 (footer)
```

I believe my main problem stems from the fact that all the child elements of 2a are floated left.

All the answers I've found talk about adding 100% height the parent containers, including the html and body tags. But I can't just go through and add height: 100%; to all every ascending parent because it ends up breaking my layout. Specifically so, when I add height 100% to my main content wrapper, div 2.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norsewulf/Duy9M/) I made that represents my problem quite well.

Comment: You could add `height:100%` to the very highest parent, then add `height:inherit` to the parent of the the closest parent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Percentage heights are calculated from the parent element, pixel heights aren't. That means you would need to set height on each level **ONLY** if all of the heights need to be in percentage.
You can set `min-height` on `2a2` with a pixel value, so it won't get any smaller than that, but it will able to expand beyond that value. And then you set `height: 100%` on `2a2a`. This will work because the parent element(2a2) has an absolute value in px.

**Edit:**
To make the 3 divs fill the rest of the container regardless of the content, you have to use the **padding-bottom, margin-bottom** trick. Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/mcIvw).

Comment: This didn't work either. But I hadn't mentioned the fact that my divs are being floated, which is quite important no doubt. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: First of all, you had a typo in your fiddle. You put `class="stretcha"` but then selected it with `.stretcha`. I'll add the solution to the answer.

Comment: That is a nice trick, and it would work great if my concern was background colors or something along those lines. However I truly the heights to be equal as I'm doing this so that I can center align the data within those elements.

After realizing the floats were my main issue, I don't believe this is possible without javascript. That's fine. I'm using Chris Coyiers [Equal Height Blocks in Rows](http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/) script and it's almost getting the job done. Just needs a little tweaking for fluid widths.

Comment: Although this solution won't work for me, it was the best answer and may work well for others. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you tell me EXACTLY what you are trying to achieve? Maybe we are going the wrong way. There may be another solution.

Comment: `min-height` in px on a parent of a child with percentage height doesn't work for me. Only setting `height` for the parent works.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `2a2`'s `position: relative` and the `2a2a`'s `position: absolute`. You can then add `top: 0; bottom: 0;` and the `2a2a` gets stretched to the full height of its parent.

a jsFiddle is always helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/REh4b/

Comment: This doesn't work, I think because my divs are being floated. Probably should have mentioned that... I've updated the original question.